# SQL Report Builder: Can't get dataset value to appear on report

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

My report is perfect with the exception of one thing: getting a dataset value to appear. More specifically, I have a sales report and I want to be able to affix to each group of customers the name of the salesperson they belong to.

Here's a shot of the report. Notice the salesperson's name (highlighted) is clearly there, just as the other values, but for some reason, it doesn't want to appear.
[image]

Additionally, when I select two salespeople (multi-value param, all is well there) I am seeing an `#Error` placeholder where one of the salesperson's name should be and a blank for the other one:
[image]

Other than this one value, everything pulls correctly. To make things even stranger (from my perspective, granted) I can put any other value in that exact same cell and it will populate:
[image]
[image]

What in the world is going on here??

Comment: For anyone else who might be having a similar issue, mine was rooted in my query. I was using two separate queries to dump into two separate temp tables, and using a join with those two temp tables I was doing my select statement to populate my dataset. I did not have the salesperson name in my select statement. The fact that it was even showing up at all as an option is what threw me, (and why it didn't occur to me to check my query) so it must have been some weird artifact.